# Function for mergin every five .txt files

Tags: bash, files, merge

I have a problem, my folder contains 1500 .txt files. I need to write a function to merge every five into one. Now I'm doing it like this:

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt >> 1a.txt
```

But changing numbers is taking ages, do you have any function so that I can make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your files are numbered sequentially:

```bash
for i in {1..1500..5}; do
  cat "$i.txt" "$((i+1)).txt" "$((i+2)).txt" "$((i+3)).txt" "$((i+4)).txt" > "${i}a.txt"
done
```

This uses [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to generate the base values, and [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) to calculate the remaining values.

Comment: Thank U Stephen, i can accept it in 5min :) will do so :) Maybe U have any ide how to merge those .txt file into 1a.docx instead of .txt?

Comment: You’d have to convert the text files into `.docx` format, using a tool such as `unoconv`. As far as I’m aware, you can’t concatenate text files directly into `.docx` format.

Comment: thank U very much :)

Comment: you can use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert plain text to .docx.  e.g. `pandoc -o "{$i}a.docx" "$i.txt" "$((i+1)).txt" "$((i+2)).txt" "$((i+3)).txt" "$((i+4)).txt".    or `pandoc -o "${i}a.docx" $(printf "%i.txt " $(seq "$i" "$((i+4))"))`

Comment: Thank U cas :) have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
# Set the nullglob shell option to make globbing patterns
# expand to nothing if pattern does not match existing
# files (instead of remaining unexpanded).
shopt -s nullglob

# Get list of files into list of positional parameters.
# Avoid the files matching "*a.txt".
set -- *[!a].txt

# Concatenate five files at a time for as long as
# there are five or more files in the list.
while [ "$#" -ge 5 ]; do
    cat "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" >"${n}a.txt"

    n=$(( n + 1 ))
    shift 5
done

# Handle any last files if number of files
# was not a factor of five.
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    cat "$@" >"${n}a.txt"
fi
```

This does the concatenation in a loop, five files at a time, to output files called `1a.txt`, `2a.txt` etc.  It does not assume that the files have special names other than that they have a `.txt` filename suffix, but the code will avoid files matching `*a.txt` since these are the output files.

Comment: Kusalananda thank U also :)